# Moving Images between Pirhana Websites

Tags: piranha-cms

When uploading images on my local development environment, and uploading the contents of the Uploads and Content Folders up to the live environment the images do not show even after updating the application pool - do you know what step i am missing.  I am using Piranha in passive mode?

Answer (score 0):

Well without any further information it's hard to come up with something that will qualify as an answer :) However, if you have copied **both** the database **and** the binary files located in `~/App_Data/Content/` my guess would be that Windows is playing a prank on you and that the IIS pool of the live environment either:

1. Doesn't have permission to access the App_Data/Content folder, or
2. That permissions from your dev server have been copied to the live server so that the IIS app pool doesn't have permission to the copied files.

Regards

Håkan